# Unable to mount a volume into a pod in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod, which is querying an AWS service using Boto. This pod runs in kubernetes cluster in EKS.

When running on a real cluster, we use ServiceAccount/Role/RoleBinding to give the Pod permission to acquire an IAM role.

But when I run it locally, using `kind`, I want it to use credentials that are in my `~/.aws` directory.

So I mount the volumes as follows:

```
    volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/run/datadog
        type: ""
      name: dsdsocket
    - hostPath:
        path: /Users/me/.aws
        type: DirectoryOrCreate
      name: aws
```

And use them in the pod as follows:

```
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/run/datadog
        name: dsdsocket
        readOnly: true
      - mountPath: /root/.aws
        name: aws
        readOnly: true
```

I have checked that there are credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`

But the directory just shows up as empty inside the pod:

```
root@the_pod:/app# ls -al /root/.aws
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 12 19:33 .
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 May  9 17:22 ..
```

NOTE: I have tried mounting the actual credentials file in `~/.aws/credentials` too, but it doesnt mount either.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't worked with kind, but it's very possible that the filesystem visible to kubernetes is not your host filesystem but is instead a container filesystem, which doesn't have your home directory in it. It might be easier to provide your AWS credentials as environment variables (possibly via a `Secret`).

Comment: your pod is getting schedule on that specific node on which file exist ? it could work as in kind you might be running single node server or have same backend file system

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use [extra mounts](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-mounts) while creating the kind cluster, it is used to pass through storage on the host to a kind node for persisting data, mounting through code, etc.

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  # add a mount from /path/to/my/files on the host to /files on the node
  extraMounts:
  - hostPath: /path/to/my/files/
    containerPath: /files
    # optional: if set, the mount is read-only.
    # default false
    readOnly: true
    propagation: HostToContainer
```

Creating a kind cluster with a custom config file:

```sh
$ kind create cluster --config=kind-config.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for that link. Just below the section you pasted I see this:

NOTE: If you are using Docker for Mac or Windows check that the hostPath is included in the Preferences -> Resources -> File Sharing.

For more information see the Docker file sharing guide.

--

So i should try that and see.